# Why does fileManager:copyItemAtURL cause "Permission Denied" issue after upgrade to iOS 16.5

Tags: ios, objective-c, copy, permission-denied

My app uses the objective-c method `[fileManager copyItemAtURL:xxx toURL:xxx error:&error]` to copy files from the app container to sandbox. Previously it worked well, but after my phone upgrade to 16.5+, it always meet issue, as

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "“isChrome.js” couldn’t be copied because you don’t have permission to access “browser”.
UserInfo={
  NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/xxx/myapp.app/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/browser/isChrome.js, 
  NSUserStringVariant=( Copy ),   
  NSDestinationFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/xxx/Library/NoCloud/www/apps/myapp/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/browser/isChrome.js,
  NSFilePath=/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/xxx/myapp.app/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/browser/isChrome.js, 
  NSUnderlyingError=0x283710a80 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=13 "Permission denied"}
}
```

I have big folder cordovaplugins to copy, I have tried to add for loop to copy subfolders one by one, it get the same result, some subfolder has permission denied issue, but different runs may get different subfolder permission issues.